# How do I prove this prime number relation is false.

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

A procedure can be modeled using the equation $P_{n+1}=P_n + 2(n+1)$ where $P_0 = 41$
You get $(41, 43, 47, 53, 61....)$. The question is, does this recursive relation continue to give prime numbers forever? I know the answer is no but I don't know how I would attempt to prove this.  I thought about induction but I got stuck.  I thought about turning the relation into an explicit equation but don't know how to do that. Don't know how to do proof by contradiction either.  Would like some help on this one

Comment: Why not just try to extend the sequence?  Alternatively, you can solve the recursion (to get a quadratic in $n$) in which case it will be obvious that they are not all prime.  The latter method might be easier, actually, as you have to go fairly far to find the first composite.

Comment: This happens to be related to [my #MegaFavNumber 262537412640768744](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqHdBPV2bkU). Check near the middle of the video

Comment: you go 41 to 43. Then you skip an odd number and go to 47.  you then skip 2 odd numbers and go to 53. Skip 4 odd numbers and go to 61. Continue that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is
$$P(n)= 41 + n^2 + n$$

For $n=40$, $P(n)=1681$ which is not prime (because $1681=41^2$...)

Comment: How did you obtain this?

Comment: $P_{k+1}-P_k = 2(k+1)$, so you can sum for $k=0$ to $n-1$ to get $P_n - P_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2(k+1) = n(n+1)$. So $P_n = P_0 + n^2 + n$.